# Writing a recursive function XSLT/XPath for computing new values

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to write a recursive function that computes new values. The basic idea of what motivates me is that given levels of an outline, I want to compute new levels such that the numbers are always sequential (that is, you can't immediately go from say level 2 to level 5) but while respecting the original relationships.

Given an input like this (note inputs could be quite different):

```
<root>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="4">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="8">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="8">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="9">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="3">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="8">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="4">yo</item>
</root>
```

I want this output

```
<root>
    <item outlinePos="0">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="0">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
</root>
```

I am using XSLT 2/XPath 2. This is what I have so far but I am not getting the right results, I know where the problem is (begins with the fifth item in the input data); I've included comments explaining what I'm trying to do:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[@outlinePos]">
    <xsl:element name="item">
        <xsl:attribute name="outlinePos" select="test:newLevel(.)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name(.)!='outlinePos'] | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="test:newLevel">
    <xsl:param name="context"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($context/preceding-sibling::item[1])"> <!-- if we don't have any preceding-sibling items, then we know we are at level 0 -->
            <xsl:sequence select="0"/> <!-- start at 0 not 1 -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$context/@outlinePos > $context/preceding-sibling::item[1]/@outlinePos"> <!-- if the current item is greater than the previous item, then we know it should come immediately after the previous item so find the level for the previous item and increment it by one -->
            <xsl:sequence select="test:newLevel($context/preceding-sibling::item[1])+1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$context/@outlinePos = $context/preceding-sibling::item[1]/@outlinePos"> <!-- if the current item equals the previous item, then we know the levels should be the same, but we need to know the previous level so find it -->
            <xsl:sequence select="test:newLevel($context/preceding-sibling::item[1])"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$context/@outlinePos &lt; $context/preceding-sibling::item[1]/@outlinePos"> <!-- if the current item is less than the previous item, then we know the new level will depend on the closest value that is either equal to the current value or less than the current value; if it is the latter, then we need to increment the final result -->

            <xsl:variable name="curOutlinePos" select="$context/@outlinePos"/>

            <!-- the next two variables here is the part that doesn't work... Neither are computing the expected values -->
            <xsl:variable name="positionClosestOutlinePosEquals" select="count($context/preceding-sibling::item[1][(@outlinePos = $curOutlinePos)]/preceding-sibling::item)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="positionClosestOutlinePosLessThan" select="count($context/preceding-sibling::item[1][(@outlinePos &lt; $curOutlinePos)]/preceding-sibling::item)"/>
            <xsl:message>Note Equals: <xsl:value-of select="$positionClosestOutlinePosEquals"/> Less than: <xsl:value-of select="$positionClosestOutlinePosLessThan"/></xsl:message>

            <!-- Once the above variables compute the right values (by selecting the right nodes), then we'll need to update the following  -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$positionClosestOutlinePosEquals &lt; $positionClosestOutlinePosLessThan">
                    <xsl:sequence select="test:newLevel($context/preceding-sibling::item[1][(@outlinePos = $curOutlinePos)])"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:sequence select="test:newLevel($context/preceding-sibling::item[1][(@outlinePos &lt; $curOutlinePos)])+1"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:sequence select="9999998"/> <!-- for testing purposes, 9999998 means "not processed", just have to make sure test data does not use 9999998 as a @outlinePos value -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here is a simple solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@outlinePos">
   <xsl:attribute name="outlinePos" select="my:level(..)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:level" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="pElem" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vOrigLevel" select="$pElem/@outlinePos/number()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vPrecedingElem" select=
   "$pElem/preceding-sibling::item[@outlinePos/number() le $vOrigLevel][1]"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "if(not($vPrecedingElem))
      then 0
      else if($vPrecedingElem/@outlinePos/number() lt $vOrigLevel)
       then my:level($vPrecedingElem) +1
       else if($vPrecedingElem/@outlinePos/number() eq $vOrigLevel)
         then my:level($vPrecedingElem)
         else (: Impossible to happen :) -999
   "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="4">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="8">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="8">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="9">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="3">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="8">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="4">yo</item>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
    <item outlinePos="0">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="0">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="1">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
    <item outlinePos="2">yo</item>
</root>
```

Comment: That is simplicity itself. Thank you.